# Footnote in sagej article throws \itshape error

Tags: tables, footnotes

I want to add footnote just after one column longtable to explain my abbreviation so i write it like this:

```
\documentclass[Afour,enotez,sageh,times,fleqn,doublespace]{sagej}
\usepackage{longtable, multirow,multicol,float,moreverb,url}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\twocolumn
some text in two sided column
\onecolumn
\begin{longtable}[!H]{lllllllll}
\label{Table:CalculatingResult}\\
\caption{caption}\\
\hline
DistrictID&SchoolID&TPR&TPQ\footnotemark[2]&CSR\footnotemark[3]&CSQ\fo
otnotemark[4]&TPQD\footnotemark[5]&CSQD&education quality per district 
\\
\endfirsthead
\midrule

\multirow{6}{*}{1} & 1 & 20.92 & 0.7543 & 25.1 & 0.7414 &\multirow{6}{*}{ 0.556} &\multirow{6}{*}{ 0.5507} &\multirow{6}{*}{ 1.1067}  \\
& 2 & 24.75 & 0.5199 & 29.7 & 0.4942  \\
& 3 & 26.94 & 0.4158 & 30.53 & 0.4576  \\
& 4 & 29.25 & 0.3229 & 35.1 & 0.2868   \\
& 5 & 19.83 & 0.8375 & 23.8 & 0.8286 \\
& 7 & 25.43 & 0.4856 & 29.67 & 0.4956   \\
\hline

\multirow{11}{*}{2} & 8 & 22 & 0.6799 & 26.4 & 0.6628 &\multirow{11}{*}{0.604} &\multirow{11}{*}{ 0.5927}  &\multirow{11}{*}{1.1967}   \\
& 10 & 23.42 & 0.5926 & 28.1 & 0.571 &  &  &  \\
& 11 & 24.29 & 0.5441 & 28.33 & 0.5595 &  &  &  \\
& 15 & 28.94 & 0.3345 & 32.8 & 0.3668 &  &  &  \\
& 16 & 29.42 & 0.3166 & 35.3 & 0.2803 &  &  &  \\
& 17 & 18 & 1 & 21.6 & 1 &  &  &  \\
& 18 & 23.08 & 0.6125 & 27.7 & 0.5916 &  &  &  \\
& 19 & 22.33 & 0.6586 & 26.8 & 0.6402 &  &  &  \\
& 22 & 21 & 0.7485 & 25.2 & 0.7351 &  &  &  \\
& 24 & 23.92 & 0.5643 & 28.7 & 0.5412 &  &  &  \\
& 25 & 23.42 & 0.5926 & 28.1 & 0.571 &  &  &  \\
\hline

\multirow{11}{*}{3}& 20 & 27.12 & 0.408 & 30.37 & 0.4645 &\multirow{11}{*}{0.3644}&\multirow{11}{*}{ 0.3661} &\multirow{11}{*}{0.7305} \\
& 23 & 27.33 & 0.399 & 30.75 & 0.4482  \\
& 26 & 28.93 & 0.3349 & 33.38 & 0.3456 \\
& 27 & 29.45 & 0.3155 & 34.11 & 0.3199 \\
& 32 & 22.56 & 0.6442 & 25.38 & 0.7238 \\
& 33 & 27.08 & 0.4097 & 32.5 & 0.3781  \\
& 44 & 27.75 & 0.3815 & 33.3 & 0.3484  \\
& 47 & 29.31 & 0.3207 & 34.64 & 0.3019 \\
& 53 & 25.86 & 0.4649 & 30.17 & 0.4732 \\
& 55 & 28.67 & 0.3448 & 34.4 & 0.31    \\
& 61 & 27.08 & 0.4097 & 32.5 & 0.3781  \\
& 64 & 29.75 & 0.3047 & 35.7 & 0.2676  \\
& 78 & 41.67 & 0 & 46.88 & 0  \\
\hline

\multirow{10}{*}{4}& 6 & 27.32 & 0.3994 & 31.63 & 0.412 &\multirow{10}{*}{0.4142}&\multirow{10}{*}{0.4287}  &\multirow{10}{*}{0.8429}  \\
& 9 & 24.17 & 0.5506 & 29 & 0.5268     \\
& 30 & 22.19 & 0.6676 & 25.36 & 0.7251 \\
& 38 & 30.61 & 0.2748 & 35.2 & 0.2835  \\
& 50 & 27.91 & 0.3749 & 32.32 & 0.3849 \\
& 51 & 27.55 & 0.3898 & 32.85 & 0.3649 \\
& 62 & 29.61 & 0.3097 & 33.31 & 0.3481 \\
& 75 & 27.5 & 0.3918 & 31.43 & 0.42    \\
& 79 & 27.61 & 0.3873 & 31.7 & 0.4092  \\
& 80 & 27.4 & 0.396 & 31.62 & 0.4124   \\
\hline

\multirow{10}{*}{5}& 12 & 28.75 & 0.3417 & 32.86 & 0.3646 &\multirow{10}{*}{0.3451} &\multirow{10}{*}{0.3525} &\multirow{10}{*}{0.6976}  \\
& 28 & 27.75 & 0.3815 & 31.71 & 0.4088 \\
& 34 & 30.5 & 0.2785 & 34.86 & 0.2946  \\
& 52 & 27.74 & 0.3819 & 31.9 & 0.4012  \\
& 56 & 29.58 & 0.3108 & 35.5 & 0.2739  \\
& 57 & 26.59 & 0.4313 & 30.39 & 0.4636 \\
& 59 & 33.35 & 0.1897 & 38.35 & 0.19 & \\
& 66 & 26.13 & 0.4523 & 30.15 & 0.4741 \\
& 70 & 27.75 & 0.3815 & 33.3 & 0.3484  \\
& 83 & 29.82 & 0.3022 & 34.53 & 0.3056 \\
\hline

\multirow{8}{*}{6}& 14 & 22.55 & 0.6448 & 27.56 & 0.599 &\multirow{8}{*}{0.5893} &\multirow{8}{*}{ 0.5734} &\multirow{8}{*}{1.1627}  \\
& 21 & 22 & 0.6799 & 26.4 & 0.6628 \\
& 29 & 22.67 & 0.6373 & 27.2 & 0.6182 \\
& 39 & 21.83 & 0.6911 & 26.2 & 0.6744  \\
& 60 & 22.92 & 0.6221 & 27.5 & 0.6021 \\
& 65 & 25.17 & 0.4985 & 30.2 & 0.4719 \\
& 76 & 25.17 & 0.4985 & 30.2 & 0.4719 \\
& 77 & 26.35 & 0.4421 & 29.87 & 0.4866\\
\hline

\multirow{4}{*}{7}& 31 & 30.88 & 0.2657 & 34 & 0.3237 &\multirow{4}{*}{0.3029} &\multirow{4}{*}{0.337}  &\multirow{4}{*}{ 0.6398} \\
& 35 & 29.61 & 0.3097 & 33.31 & 0.3481 \\
& 36 & 29.64 & 0.3086 & 33.68 & 0.3349 \\
& 37 & 29.13 & 0.3274 & 33.5 & 0.3413  \\
\hline

\multirow{3}{*}{8}& 13 & 31.88 & 0.2335 & 36.43 & 0.2451 &\multirow{3}{*}{0.3344}  &\multirow{3}{*}{0.3398}  &\multirow{3}{*}{0.6742}  \\
& 63 & 27.14 & 0.4071 & 32.79 & 0.3672 \\
& 71 & 28.22 & 0.3624 & 31.75 & 0.4072 \\
\hline

\multirow{9}{*}{9}& 41 & 31.65 & 0.2408 & 36.4 & 0.246 &\multirow{9}{*}{0.3862}&\multirow{9}{*}{ 0.3614} &\multirow{9}{*}{ 0.7476} \\
& 42 & 23.08 & 0.6125 & 30 & 0.4808 &  &  &  \\
& 43 & 25.81 & 0.4673 & 30.11 & 0.4759 &  &  &  \\
& 45 & 28.84 & 0.3383 & 32.77 & 0.3679 &  &  &  \\
& 48 & 25.95 & 0.4607 & 32.06 & 0.395 &  &  &  \\
& 54 & 30.61 & 0.2748 & 34.44 & 0.3086 &  &  &  \\
& 68 & 27.92 & 0.3745 & 33.5 & 0.3413 &  &  &  \\
& 73 & 27.33 & 0.399 & 32.8 & 0.3668 &  &  &  \\
& 87 & 29.67 & 0.3076 & 35.6 & 0.2707 &  &  &  \\
\hline

\multirow{8}{*}{10}& 40 & 26.76 & 0.4237 & 30.33 & 0.4662 &\multirow{8}{*}{ 0.5775} &\multirow{8}{*}{ 0.5715} &\multirow{8}{*}{1.149}  \\
& 46 & 25.92 & 0.4621 & 31.1 & 0.4335 \\
& 49 & 20.38 & 0.7944 & 26.5 & 0.6571 \\
& 58 & 27.42 & 0.3952 & 32.9 & 0.3631 \\
& 67 & 25.12 & 0.501 & 28.47 & 0.5525 \\
& 69 & 23.75 & 0.5738 & 28.5 & 0.551  \\
& 72 & 21.5 & 0.7134 & 25.8 & 0.6981  \\
& 74 & 20.89 & 0.7565 & 23.5 & 0.8501 \\
\hline

\multirow{3}{*}{13}& 82 & 27.4 & 0.396 & 30.44 & 0.4615 &\multirow{3}{*}{ 0.4194 }&\multirow{3}{*}{0.5401}  &\multirow{3}{*}{0.9594}  \\
& 84 & 29.21 & 0.3244 & 34.08 & 0.3209 \\
& 85 & 24.41 & 0.5377 & 23.67 & 0.8378 \\
\midrule
14 & 86 & 19 & 0.9073 & 22.8 & 0.9024 & 0.9073 & 0.9024 & 1.8079 \\
\bottomrule
\label{Table:Result}


\end{longtable}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
%do not draw the footnoterule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
\footnotetext[1]{ First footnote on the caption}
\footnotetext[2]{ Second footnote on the heading}
\footnotetext[3]{ Third footnote inside table's body}
\end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
some text some text 
some text some text
\end{document}
```

sagej class

```
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Please  be  aware that the use of this LaTeX class file is governed by the
%following conditions:
%
% based on the original LaTeX ARTICLE DOCUMENT STYLE
% Copyright (C) 1988, 1989 by Leslie Lamport
%
% Copyright (c) 2013 SAGE Publications. All rights reserved.
%
%Rules of Use
%
%% You are NOT ALLOWED to change this file.
%
%
%This class file is made available for use by authors who wish to prepare an
%article for publication in a SAGE Publications journal. 
%The user may not exploit any part of the class file commercially.
%
%This class file is provided on an `as is'  basis, without warranties of any
%kind, either expressed or implied, including but not limited to warranties of
%title, or  implied warranties of merchantablility or fitness for  a
%particular purpose. There will be no duty on the author[s] of the software
%or SAGE Publications to correct any errors or defects in the software.
%Any statutory rights you may have remain unaffected by your acceptance of
%these rules of use.
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% Created by Alistair Smith, Sunrise Setting Ltd, 27 July 2013
%
% sagej.cls --- For SAGE Publications
%
%  9/6/15 Endnote bug fix.
% 24/6/15 Add "comma" to vancouver natbib line; remove figure extension; Review option added.
% 14/1/17 SAGE graphic removed and replaced by drawn box.

\def\update{2017/01/17 v1.20}

\newcommand{\journalclass}{sagej.cls}
\newcommand{\journalclassshort}{sagej}
%\newcommand{\DOI}{XXX}

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{sagej}[\update\ \journalclass]

%\newcommand\hmmax{0}

\newif\if@timesfont
\DeclareOption{times}{%
\@timesfonttrue}

\newif\if@doublespace
\DeclareOption{doublespace}{%
\@doublespacetrue}

\newif\if@sageh
\DeclareOption{sageh}{%
\@sagehtrue}

\newif\if@sagev
\DeclareOption{sagev}{%
\@sagevtrue}

\newif\if@sageapa
\DeclareOption{sageapa}{%
\@sageapatrue}

%Setup the trim and text areas
\newif\if@shortAfour
\DeclareOption{shortAfour}{%
\@shortAfourtrue}

\newif\if@Afour
\DeclareOption{Afour}{%
\@Afourtrue}

\newif\if@MCfour
\DeclareOption{MCfour}{%
\@MCfourtrue}

\newif\if@PCfour
\DeclareOption{PCfour}{%
\@PCfourtrue}

\newif\if@Royal
\DeclareOption{Royal}{%
\@Royaltrue}

\newif\if@Crown
\DeclareOption{Crown}{%
\@Crowntrue}

\newif\if@Review
\DeclareOption{Review}{%
\@Reviewtrue}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{article}

\if@timesfont
\RequirePackage{times}
\usepackage[scaled=.95]{helvet}
\fi
\if@doublespace
\RequirePackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\fi

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{latexsym,ifthen,rotating,calc,textcase,booktabs,color,endnotes}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy,amsmath,amsthm}
%\RequirePackage{bm}
\RequirePackage[errorshow]{tracefnt}

\@twosidetrue
\flushbottom
\frenchspacing

\let\sagesf\sf
\if@PCfour
\let\sagesf\rm
\fi

%papersize={width,height}
\if@shortAfour
\usepackage[text={170.5mm,226mm},%
papersize={210mm,280mm},%
columnsep=12pt,%
headsep=21pt,%
centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{ftnright}
\fi

%papersize={width,height}
\if@Afour
\usepackage[text={174mm,258mm},%
papersize={210mm,297mm},%
columnsep=12pt,%
headsep=21pt,%
centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{ftnright}
\fi

%papersize={width,height}
\if@MCfour
\usepackage[text={151.5mm,196mm},%
papersize={189mm,246mm},%
columnsep=12pt,%
headsep=21pt,%
centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{ftnright}
\fi

%papersize={width,height}
\if@PCfour
\usepackage[text={138mm,198mm},%
papersize={170mm,242mm},%
columnsep=12pt,%
headsep=21pt,%
centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{ftnright}
\fi

%papersize={width,height}%single column
\if@Royal
\usepackage[text={124mm,185mm},%
papersize={156mm,234mm},%
columnsep=12pt,%
headsep=21pt,%
centering]{geometry}
\fi

%papersize={width,height}%single column
\if@Crown
\usepackage[text={146.5mm,183mm},%
papersize={7.25in,9.5in},%
columnsep=12pt,%
headsep=21pt,%
centering]{geometry}
\fi

%For Review Single column, 12pt
\if@Review
\usepackage[text={124mm,185mm},%
papersize={156mm,234mm},%
columnsep=12pt,%
headsep=21pt,%
centering]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12}{14pt}\selectfont}
\fi

\parindent 1em

\hyphenpenalty=1000
\pretolerance=8000
\tolerance=9500
\hbadness=8000
\vbadness=9000
\displaywidowpenalty=0
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\lefthyphenmin=3%
\righthyphenmin=3%
\brokenpenalty=10000%

\thinmuskip = 3mu
\medmuskip = 4mu
\thickmuskip = 5mu

\setcounter{topnumber}{10}
\def\topfraction{1}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{10}
\def\bottomfraction{0.8}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{10}
\def\textfraction{0}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.95}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{10}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{0.95}
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{1}

\renewcommand\small{%
   \@setfontsize\small\@ixpt{10.5}%
   \abovedisplayskip 8.5\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus2\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               %\parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\newcommand{\refsize}{\fontsize{9}{12pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{8}{10pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\scriptsize}{\fontsize{7.0}{8.5pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\large}{\fontsize{12}{14pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\titlesize}{\fontsize{18.0}{20pt}\selectfont}

\newbox\absbox
\def\abstract{\lrbox\absbox\minipage{\textwidth}%
  \sagesf\normalsize%
  \section*{\normalsize Abstract}\vskip -1.5mm%
  }
\def\endabstract{\endminipage\endlrbox}

\def\keywords#1{%
  \gdef\@keywords{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}{\normalsize\sagesf \textbf{Keywords}}\\ \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{#1}\end{minipage}}}
\let\@keywords\@empty

\skip\footins 20pt plus  8pt
%\gdef\footnoterule{}
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@
  \hrule \@width \columnwidth \kern 3mm}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\parindent 1em%
\noindent{$\m@th^{\@thefnmark}$}#1}

\newcommand{\email}[1]{%
  \gdef\@email{%
\footnotetext[0]{\sagesf Email: #1}}}
\let\@email\@empty

\def\corrauth#1{\gdef\@corrauth{%
\footnotetext[0]{\par\vskip-3pt\sagesf\noindent\textbf{Corresponding author:}\\ #1}}}
\let\@corrauth\@empty

\def\affiliation#1{%
  \gdef\@affiliation{%
    \footnotetext[0]{\sagesf #1}}}
\let\@affiliation\@empty

\def\affilnum#1{${}^{\text{{#1}}}$}

\renewcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
     \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
       \fi
    \else
      \newpage
      \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
      \@maketitle
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{title}\label{FirstPage}\@affiliation\@corrauth\@email%
  \endgroup
  %\setcounter{footnote}{0}%
    \global\let\affiliation\relax
   \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\@affiliation\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}
\def\@maketitle{%
\if@Royal
\vspace*{-20pt}
\fi
\if@Crown
\vspace*{-20pt}
\fi
\vspace*{-34pt}%
\null%
\begin{center}
\if@PCfour
\begin{rm}
\else
\begin{sf}
\fi
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth-57.625mm}
  \vskip 12.5pt%
    {\raggedright\titlesize\textbf{\@title} \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    \vskip 12.5mm%
    \end{minipage}\hspace{15mm}\begin{minipage}[t]{42.625mm}
\hbox{}\scriptsize\journalname\\
\hbox{}\volumenumber(\issuenumber):\startpage--\endpage\\ 
\hbox{}\copyright The Author(s) \volumeyear\\
\hbox{}Reprints and permission:\\
\hbox{}sagepub.co.uk/journalsPermissions.nav\\
\hbox{}DOI: 10.1177/ToBeAssigned\\
\hbox{}www.sagepub.com/\\[2.3pt]
%\hbox{}\includegraphics[height=4mm]{SAGE_Logo}
\hbox{}{\fboxsep 1.5pt\framebox[14mm]{{\normalsize SAGE}}}
\end{minipage}
{\par\large%
\if@Royal
      \vspace*{6mm}
      \fi
      \if@Crown
      \vspace*{6mm}
      \fi%
      \lineskip .5em%
      {\raggedright\textbf{\@author}
      \par}}
     \vskip 40pt%
    {\noindent\usebox\absbox\par}
    {\vspace{20pt}%
      %
      {\noindent\normalsize\@keywords}\par}
      \if@PCfour
      \end{rm}
      \else
      \end{sf}
      \fi
      \end{center}
      \if@Royal
      \vspace*{-4.5mm}
      \fi
      \if@Crown
      \vspace*{-4.5mm}
      \fi
      \vspace{22pt}
        \par%
  }

\def\startpage{\pageref{FirstPage}}
\def\endpage{\pageref{LastPage}}
\def\volumeyear{0000}
\def\volumenumber{XX}
\def\issuenumber{X}
\def\journalname{Journal Title}

\def\runninghead#1{\markboth{{#1}}{}}

\def\ps@title{%
\def\@oddhead{\parbox{\textwidth}{\mbox{}\\[-1pt]%
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}%
}}%
\let\@evenhead\@oddhead
\def\@oddfoot{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
{\scriptsize{\it Prepared using \textsf{\journalclass} [Version: \update]}}}}
\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}

\def\ps@sagepage{%
\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
\def\@evenhead{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
\normalsize\sagesf\thepage\hfill\itshape\journalname\ \volumenumber(\issuenumber)\\[-6pt]
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.25pt}}}
\def\@oddhead{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
\normalsize\sagesf{\itshape{\leftmark}}\hfill\thepage\\[-6pt]
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.25pt}}}
\def\@evenfoot{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
\scriptsize{\it Prepared using \textsf{\journalclass}}}}
\def\@oddfoot{\@evenfoot}
}

%\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{{\csname the#1\endcsname.}\hspace{0.5em}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}

\newdimen\@bls                              
\@bls=\baselineskip

\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {1.2\@bls  plus .3\@bls minus .1\@bls}%
                                   {5pt\@afterindentfalse}%
                                   {\sagesf\large\bfseries\raggedright}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {0.9\@bls plus .3\@bls minus .1\@bls}%
                                     {4pt\@afterindentfalse}%
                                     {\sagesf\large\itshape\raggedright}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {0.5\@bls plus .3\@bls minus .1\@bls}%
                                     {-0.5em\@afterindentfalse}%
                                     {\sagesf\normalsize\itshape}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{1em}%
                                     {0.3\@bls plus .3\@bls minus .1\@bls}%
                                     {-0.5em\@afterindentfalse}%
                                     {\sagesf\normalsize\itshape}}

\def\enumerate{\ifnum \@enumdepth >3 \@toodeep\else
      \advance\@enumdepth \@ne
      \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}\list
      {\csname label\@enumctr\endcsname}{\usecounter
        {\@enumctr}\itemsep 0pt\parsep 0pt
         \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}\fi}

\let\endenumerate =\endlist

\def\itemize{\ifnum \@itemdepth >3 \@toodeep\else \advance\@itemdepth \@ne
\edef\@itemitem{labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth}%
\list{\csname\@itemitem\endcsname}{\itemsep 0pt\parsep 0pt
\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}\fi}

\let\enditemize =\endlist

\RequirePackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{sageperiod}{.\hspace*{1ex}}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont={sf,bf},textfont=sf,labelsep=sageperiod,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup[table]{position=top,labelsep=sageperiod,font=small,labelfont={sf,bf},textfont=sf,justification=raggedright,skip=2pt,singlelinecheck=false}

\def\@begintheorem#1#2[#3]{%
  \deferred@thm@head{\the\thm@headfont \thm@indent
    \@ifempty{#1}{\let\thmname\@gobble}{\let\thmname\@iden}%
    \@ifempty{#2}{\let\thmnumber\@gobble}{\let\thmnumber\@iden}%
    \@ifempty{#3}{\let\thmnote\@gobble}{\let\thmnote\@iden}%
    \thm@swap\swappedhead\thmhead{#1}{#2\the\thm@headpunct}{#3}%
    %\the\thm@headpunct
    \thmheadnl % possibly a newline.
    \hskip\thm@headsep
  }%
  \ignorespaces}

\def\thmhead@plain#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont #3. }}}

\newenvironment{acks}[1]%
{\subsection*{\normalsize\sagesf\bfseries Acknowledgements}\begin{refsize}\noindent #1}%
{\end{refsize}}

\newenvironment{funding}[1]%
{\subsection*{\normalsize\sagesf\bfseries Funding}\begin{refsize}\noindent #1}%
{\end{refsize}}

\newenvironment{sm}[1]%
{\subsection*{\normalsize\sagesf\bfseries Supplemental material}\begin{refsize}\noindent #1}%
{\end{refsize}}

\newenvironment{dci}[1]%
{\subsection*{\normalsize\sagesf\bfseries Declaration of conflicting interests}\begin{refsize}\noindent #1}%
{\end{refsize}} 

\newenvironment{biog}[1]%
{\subsection*{\normalsize\sagesf\bfseries Author biography}\begin{refsize}\noindent #1}%
{\end{refsize}}

\newenvironment{biogs}[1]%
{\subsection*{\normalsize\sagesf\bfseries Author Biographies}\begin{refsize}\noindent #1}%
{\end{refsize}}

%Endnotes
\def\enotesize{\refsize}

\def\enoteheading{\subsection*{\normalsize\sagesf\bfseries\notesname}%
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip}

%\renewcommand\makeenmark{\theenmark.\hspace{0.75em}}

\renewcommand{\enoteformat}{%
   \rightskip\z@ \leftskip15pt \parindent=0pt
   \leavevmode{\makebox[0cm][r]{%
   \hbox to15pt{\@theenmark.\hfill}}}}


\newtheoremstyle{sage}
{6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}% space above
{6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}% space below
{\it}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries}% Theorem head font
{.}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.75em}% Space after theorem head
{}% Theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{sage}

\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  %AS\pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \bfseries
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  %AS\popQED
  \endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}

%\renewenvironment{thebibliography}{%
%\section*{\normalsize\refname}
%\list{}{\topsep=0\p@\parsep=0\p@
%\partopsep=0\p@\itemsep=1\p@\labelsep=0\p@\itemindent=-20\p@
%\labelwidth=0\p@\leftmargin=20\p@
%}\refsize\rm
%\def\newblock{\ }
%\sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
%\sfcode`\.=1000\relax}{\endlist}

\if@sageh
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{}{}{,}
\setlength{\bibsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\bibhang}{16pt}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\refsize}
\renewcommand\refname{{\normalsize References}}
\fi

\if@sagev
\usepackage[super,sort&compress,comma]{natbib}
%\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{}{}{,}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{#1.}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt}
%\setlength{\bibhang}{20pt}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\refsize}
\renewcommand\refname{{\normalsize References}}
\fi

\if@sageapa
%\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{mslapa}
\setlength{\bibhang}{16pt}
\@ifundefined{chapter}{\def\thebibliography#1{\section*{\refname}\list
  {\relax}{\setlength{\labelsep}{0em}
        \setlength{\itemindent}{-\bibhang}
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
        \parsep 0pt}%AS
    \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}}%
\fi

\AtEndDocument{%
\label{LastPage}}

\pagestyle{sagepage}

\if@shortAfour
\column
\fi

\if@Afour
\twocolumn
\fi

\if@MCfour
\twocolumn
\fi

\if@PCfour
\twocolumn
\fi

\normalsize
\sloppy
```

After build i get this error

```
Command \itshape invalid in math mode. ...tetext[1]{ First footnote on the caption}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I added the class file and packages .

Comment: Thanks for that, however it would be much easier, IF you can reproduce the issue with a Minimal example with for example the `article` class, to use such a class so that people don't have to load everything specific of your case. It could also help localize the issue.

Comment: Well, it seems to be an error related to the `sagej` class ...

Comment: i will rewrite the code without sajej class

Comment: yes it's sage class error, because i write the code without sajej class and its work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save a copy of the `sagej.cls` file under `sagejmod.cls` and replace line 255 of this file

```
\noindent{$\m@th^{\@thefnmark}$}#1}
```

with

```
\noindent{\textsuperscript{\@thefnmark}}#1}
```

Compile the document with `\documentclass[...]{sagejmod}`.

It seems to work without errors and provides this style of footnotes

[image]

Still, I would check (with the editor I guess) if this is the latest release of this class.

**EDIT** I am not 100% sure if this is the way to do it properly, but you can add this snippet to you preamble to correct the definition of the footnotes without modifying the class.

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\parindent 1em%
\noindent{\textsuperscript{\@thefnmark}}#1}
\makeatother
```

**EDIT** The following code is a MWE for the OP's issue

```
\documentclass[Afour,enotez,sageh,times,fleqn,doublespace]{sagej}

% Uncomment this to solve the issue
%\makeatletter
%\long\def\@makefntext#1{\parindent 1em%
%\noindent{\textsuperscript{\@thefnmark}}#1}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
%some text in two sided column
\onecolumn
A\footnotemark[1]
B\footnotemark[2]

\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
%do not draw the footnoterule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
\footnotetext[1]{ First footnote on the caption}
\footnotetext[2]{ Second footnote on the heading}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please do not recommend to change lines in the class file, but explicitly advice to change it in a copy. Direct changes may cause more harm than good.

Comment: @TeXnician My apologies. I guess I did not pay attention to that. I edited the answer to explicitly ask to modify a copy. Thanks!

Comment: is there any other solution without editing the file directly (may be change the command is main article)??

Comment: See the edit to the answer

Comment: @user943998 I added a Minimal Example in my answer for you to see how much your base code can be reduced.